# Ajax form with brackets in fields names

Tags: jquery, ajax, post

I have a little question about ajax :

When I send a basic form without ajax, I usually give a prefix to the name attribute of it's fields, so they are grouped in an array.

Ex : with `form1[a], form1[b] and form2[a]` as fields names, I will get everything grouped by the corresponding prefix.
(`form1[a, b] and form2[a]`)

Now i would like to post everything with ajax.
I'm forced to encode in JSON my array of fields because php fails to handle the brackets by ajax (I got '`form1[a"` ').
When I do var_dump($_POST), my fields aren't grouped, and their names contains the prefix !
How can i get the good result ?

I hope someone will understand my problem, thanks if you can help !

EDIT :

So, i found a way to make it work.
I couldn't serialize the entire form because the concerned inputs were the only thing i wanted, and not the rest.

So my solution is this :

Store each serialized input in an array.
Decode the string because brackets were transformed into `%5D`

```
fields.push($(this).serialize());
decodeURI(fields.join('&'));
```

Send everything...

Then in php :

```
parse_str($_POST, $data);
```

And the result is :

```
array(form1 => array(a=1, b=2), b => array(a=1))
```

YAAY :D

Answer (score 0):

Try to send `serialized` data, it's work good for me:

```
$.ajax({
    /// your parameters
    data: $('yourFormSelector').serialize()
});
```

Comment: My inputs are in a table row and not a form. I see that jquery can serialize each input separatly, but how can i regroup their data in an array/object and send them ? The result for a field is like "form1%5Ba%5D=1" Thanks.

Comment: @FC', send data `as is` to server, and group it in backend. Why client-side group?

Comment: I don't want to group them client-side, but a way to decode the json with the prefix becoming an array key.

Comment: @FC', I do not know what you want to implement, but i think you're going the wrong way...

Comment: You must be right. But using brackets in name works without ajax, i don't understand the differences. Thanks anyway, i will just drop these prefix

Comment: I found ! I will edit the question in case someone is looking for the same thing.